# Tab key is not working for some text boxes in xaml view for mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabs, tabstop

I have a Create.xaml view in wpf with mvvm , that contains text boxes and combo boxes .

When i click on TAB key middle of the text boxes are not focused (or selected),
and also not working for SHIFT + TAB .

```
<Grid  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Style="{StaticResource EntryFieldStyle}" Margin="0,9,0,2">
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtBxInventory1"  Margin="4,0,0,0"  tabIndex="0"/>
</Grid>
```

I have tried with tab index but I am not getting the solution for that. Could you please give me the solution.

Comment: Have you tried `IsTabStop` property.

Comment: No I haven't tried with IsTabStop property

Comment: Then use it and tell plz.

Comment: Hi AnjumSKan, I have tried with IsTabStop property , even though It is not working , Is any another solution for that.?

Comment: By default you can navigate to `TextBox` with Tab or Shift+Tab. There is something else in your code that prevents this. Please share the whole xaml for that `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IsTabStop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.controls.control.istabstop(v=vs.100).aspx) property for the `TextBox` to be included in tab navigation.

Set `IsTabStop = True` for your `TextBox`.

Comment: Hi AnjumSKhan, I have tried with IsTabStop property, even though I am not getting that, can provide me the another solution for that

Comment: Have you set `IsTabStop = true` for your TextBox ?

Comment: No i have set like IsTabStop = false

Comment: I tried also with ** IsTabStop = true ** But i am unable to get.

Comment: Check for multiline property.